# What is command to run android AOSP image in plain QEMU?

Tags: android, android-source, qemu

I want to test TrustZone feature in mainline QEMU and let QEMU run android image. The TrustZone feature is not in qemu-ranchu which is emulator of android built on top of old version qemu. Qemu-ranchu does not include TrustZone feature. So I have to use plain qemu to run trustzone feature on android.

I already compiled the AOSP with arm64 option and I have following image file: ramdisk.img, system.img, cache.img, userdata.img. I want to use qemu-system-aarch64 run these AOSP images.

Could anyone provide some guide line what command should I use to let qemu run these android images? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just in case, this http://www.cnx-software.com/2014/08/23/how-to-build-and-run-android-l-64-bit-arm-in-qemu/ and this http://elinux.org/images/2/29/Customizing_AOSP_for_my_Device.pdf can be useful for you

Answer (score 3):

Although I don't know what "TrustZone" is, I think you are confused - "ranchu" is a hardware definition that the *new* Emulator can use, and it, in turn is based on a much newer Qemu code base.

In any case, you can see exactly what options are being used to run qemu by the Android Emulator (which "wraps" qemu) by starting it from the command line with the -verbose flag, for example:

```
~/.android-sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_10_API_19 -verbose
```

I've had some luck running qemu directly by copying those options, and by experimenting with the values that are printed out by the Emulator "wrapper" code.

BTW, you will first need to use Studio's "AVD Manager" to make an avd to use in that command. More information about the command line use of the Emulator can be found here:

[Android Emulator Command Line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html)

Good luck!